# Fullscreen element adjust to viewport size

Tags: html, css, graphic

I'm trying to get some graphical elements to function like a resizable Finder or Windows Explorer window... no different than the ones you open and close on your computer screens. The window is basically 100% of the viewport, but with 15px margins on every side of it.

Based on my coding here, .window is only adjusting to the size of the content within it, rather than filling up the viewport 100% with respects to the margins set. I'm a noob, but I feel like this has something to do with setting the body/head height/width to 100% as well. Either way, what am I doing wrong?

```
.window {
background:url("http://theinspirationgallery.com/wallpaper/ivy/images/wp_ivy_142.jpg");
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;

}
```

Here's a link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgT5T/

Comment: I don't see what you're describing. On Chrome, with `html, body{ height: 100%; width:100%;}`, this grows to the full window size and has 15px margins on all but the right side. Not sure what's up with the right margin, though.

Comment: The body tag is included for you in jsfddles also I assume you meant `</section>` Here is an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kgT5T/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the effect you're looking for by (ab)using absolute positioning.

Here is a JSBin demo: http://jsbin.com/jovutace/1/

The CSS is simply this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.window {
    background:url("http://theinspirationgallery.com/wallpaper/ivy/images/wp_ivy_142.jpg");
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The first CSS rule sets the size of the `<html>` and `<body>` elements to take up the full view port. The `margin` and `padding` declarations remove any browser-specific styles (though I recommend a full CSS reset, of course.)

The second rule sets the `.window` div to have absolute positioning, and then effectively tacks each side 15 pixels away from that edge.

I normally don't recommend using absolute positioning, but for whatever reason there's some strange behavior happening when you use relative positioning and `height: 100%; width:100%;` on the `.window`.

In the JSBin demo, I made the HTML background yellow for contrasting purposes so it's easier to see where the edges of the image are as you change the window size.

Comment: I think we got a winner, forget about my answer. Like I forgot how much can be done with simple absolute positioning, with left right and top and bottom...

Comment: @bardzusny I like your answer, actually. I hadn't thought of using `calc()` at all, but it's a good alternative if you don't mind the fact that [IE prior to 9 doesn't support it fully](http://caniuse.com/calc).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Here was the result if you were curious. http://jsbin.com/jovutace/2

Comment: Nice! That's pretty sweet. Thanks for sharing. :)

Answer (score 1):

**http://jsfiddle.net/G6v9G/1/**

```
div {
    background:url("http://theinspirationgallery.com/wallpaper/ivy/images/wp_ivy_142.jpg");
    margin: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

< div > is your window, by the way.

We're using pretty new thing, calc()...why? Either you need to set margins in percentage (left margin + window + right margin = 100%), or count on user using modern browser.

Otherwise, just remember about "position: absolute;" - but "position: fixed;" also seems applicable to your case. Check it out.

P.S.: Why < body > element has "margin: 0;"? Forget about it, it's because by default webkit browsers are adding *some* margin to < body >. Remember to use CSS reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ (one of many)